# How to reset Spinner value to "Select by something" based on Radio Button checked

Tags: android, spinner, android-radiogroup

I have Two Radio Buttons along with Two Spinner, both are depend on another one. E.g for if I clicked Radio `Button1` means Spinner visibility hidden. same for opposite.

View and Hide is working, The Problem is, If i choose first Radio Button and choose some values in Spinner1. but now wrongly choose so i Move onto Radio Button 2 and choose some value from `Spinner2`. (Now first `Spinner1` values not change (i.e) old value selected. I think whenever change Radio Button Opposite Spinner value set to "Select By something",

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide(); //<< this for hide title bar
    setContentView(R.layout.scrap_report);


    // Permission StrictMode
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    setCurrentDateOnView();
    addListenerOnButton();

    staff_name = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);//staff spinner
    product_name = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);//product spinner
    created_date1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
    created_date2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate2);


    //spinner for customer name
    staff_name = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_scrap_staff, R.id.txt, listItems);
    staff_name.setAdapter(adapter);
    staff_name.setAdapter(new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(adapter, R.layout.scrap_staff_nthgselect, this));

    //spinner for Products
    product_name=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    adapter2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_scrap_product,R.id.txt,listItems2);
    product_name.setAdapter(adapter2);
    product_name.setAdapter(new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(adapter2,R.layout.scrap_product_nthg,this));


    final RadioGroup rgroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioType);
    final RadioButton Ta = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.type_a);
    final RadioButton Tb = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.type_b);

    rgroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()     {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if (rgroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == Ta.getId()) {
                staff_names = staff_name.getSelectedItem().toString();
                product_name.setSelection(0);
                product_name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                staff_name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else if (rgroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == Tb.getId()) {
                product_names = product_name.getSelectedItem().toString();
                staff_name.setSelection(0);
                staff_name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                product_name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });





   /* rgroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if(checkedId == R.id.type_a){
                staff_name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                product_name.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                staff_name = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            }
            else{
                staff_name.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                product_name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                product_name=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            }
        }
    });

    rgroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if (rgroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == Ta.getId()) {
                staff_names = staff_name.getSelectedItem().toString();
                product_name.setAdapter(adapter2);
            }
            else if (rgroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == Tb.getId()) {
                product_names = product_name.getSelectedItem().toString();
                staff_name.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    });*/

    Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loadbtn);
    assert submit != null;
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            staff_names = staff_name.getSelectedItem().toString();
            product_names = product_name.getSelectedItem().toString();
            createddate = created_date1.getText().toString();
            created_date = created_date2.getText().toString();
            String url_server = "http://192.168.1.13:8090/Vaari_services/getScrapRepo.php";
            new get_ScrapDate().execute(url_server);

            staff_name.setSelection(0);
            product_name.setSelection(0);

        }
    });
}
```

i tried

```
 staff_name.setSelection(0,true);
```

LogCat:

```
06-28 12:43:58.356 27966-27966/com.example.vari.new_varri E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.example.vari.new_varri, PID: 27966
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at com.example.vari.new_varri.Scrap_Report$1.onCheckedChanged(Scrap_Report.java:142)
                                                                            at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:173)
                                                                            at android.widget.RadioGroup.-wrap0(RadioGroup.java)
                                                                            at android.widget.RadioGroup$CheckedStateTracker.onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup.java:351)
                                                                            at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:159)
                                                                            at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:115)
                                                                            at android.widget.RadioButton.toggle(RadioButton.java:76)
                                                                            at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:120)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select programatically by using

```
spinnerObject.setSelection(0)
```

if still its not working then try this

```
spinnerObject.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            spinnerObject.setSelection(0);
        }
    });
```

radibutton checkedchangelistener

```
    rgroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()     {
                            @Override
                            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                                if (rgroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == Ta.getId()) {
                                    staff_names = listItems.get(spinner1Object.getSelectedItemPosition());
    spinner2Object.setSelection(0);
    spinner2Object.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    spinner1Object.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }
                                else if (rgroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == Tb.getId()) {
                                    product_names = listItems2.get(spinner2Object.getSelectedItemPosition());
    spinner1Object.setSelection(0);
    spinner1Object.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    spinner2Object.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }
                            }
                        });
```